# how to convert static HTML5 navigation menu to wordpress dynamic menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How to convert  static HTML5  navigation menu  to WordPress dynamic menu.
I want to output this HTML menu in WordPress.and  I don't know how to make ul and li in this form.
Thanks for your help.
This is my HTML5 navigation menu

```html
    <ul class="nav topnav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="index-alt2.html">Homepage 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="index-alt3.html">Homepage 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="index-alt4.html">Parallax slider</a></li>
                <li><a href="index-landingpage.html">Landing page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Features <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="components.html">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="icon-variations.html">Icon variations</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">3rd menus<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-level1">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Sub menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Sub menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Pages <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricingbox.html">Pricing boxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Portfolio <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="portfolio-2cols.html">Portfolio 2 columns</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-3cols.html">Portfolio 3 columns</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-4cols.html">Portfolio 4 columns</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio-detail.html">Portfolio detail</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Blog <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="blog-left-sidebar.html">Blog left sidebar</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog-right-sidebar.html">Blog right sidebar</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog-fullwidth.html">Blog fullwidth</a></li>
                <li><a href="post-left-sidebar.html">Post left sidebar</a></li>
                <li><a href="post-right-sidebar.html">Post right sidebar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to convert it to WordPress menu with

```php
wp_nav_menu()
```

How can I make this custom menu?
I don't want to use any plugins to make custom menu.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to register nav menu in **functions.php** like this:

```php
function register_menu(){
    register_nav_menu('main-menu', 'Main menu');
}
add_action('init', 'register_menu');
```

When you do this, new option will appear in your admin panel. Go to Appearance > Menus and start adding links, pages or whatever you want to be in your menu. You can specify depth as well. Once you are done with your menu, select location of the menu, which will in this case be your newly created 'Main menu'. Now you want to go back to your page template in code editor to display that menu. It is very hard to use **wp_nav_menu()** function to display such complex menu so we will use different approach. We will grab menu items for start:

```php
$menuLocation = get_nav_menu_locations();
$mainMenuID = $menuLocation['main-menu'];
$topMenuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($mainMenuID);
```

Now goes the main part. We are looping through menu items and displaying it's data in combination with custom html elements:

```php
<?php

$menuLocation = get_nav_menu_locations();
$mainMenuID = $menuLocation['main-menu'];
$topMenuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($mainMenuID);
                        
                // check if menu has items
                if(!empty($topMenuItems)){
                            ?>
                     <ul>
                        <?php
                                
                          foreach ($topMenuItems as $topMenuItem){
                                     //Check if menu_item_parent property is set to 0. 
                                      That means that menu item is top level item.

                                     if($topMenuItem->menu_item_parent == 0){
                                         
                              $topItemID = $topMenuItem->ID;
                              $submenuItems = array();

                              //check if there are submenu items for current top menu 
                              item.
                              foreach ($topMenuItems as $submenuItem){
                                             
                              if($submenuItem->menu_item_parent == $topItemID){
                                                 $submenuItems[] = $submenuItem;
                                             }
                                         }
  
                                        ?>
                                         <li>
<a href="<?php echo $topMenuItem->url ?>"><?php echo $topMenuItem->title ?> </a>
                                                    
                                            <?php
                                   // If there are submenu items for current item, display 
                                    them.
                                            if(!empty($submenuItems)){
                                                ?>
                                            <ul class="submenu">
                                                <?php
                                                    foreach ($submenuItems as $subitem){
                                                        ?>
                                                <li>
 <a  href="<?php echo $subitem->url ?>"><?php echo $subitem->title ?></a>
                                                </li>
                                                    <?php
                                                        
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </ul>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                         </li>
                                        <?php  
                                     }    
                                 }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                               
                            <?php
                            }
      
                        ?>
// Using this logic, you can go in depth how much you want to.
```